# Conditionally Run Code Based on Day/Time

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, time

I'm building an event based app which utilizes the Instagram API. Since the app is event based I only want to respond to Instagram API POSTs that Instagram sends to my callback on specific days and times. My plan of attack is to wrap all code after `console.log('callback hit');` in a conditional stating `if(current day/time <= upper bound && current day/time >= lower bound) {run code} else {console.log('event is not currently in progress')}`. My questions are a) is this a logical approach? and b) how would I go about referencing the "upper/lower bound" and "current day/time", ie how to code in specific days/times properly?

Code below resides in my node 'server.js' file:

```
app.post('/callback', function (req, res) {
  console.log('callback hit');

  //loop in all the new objects
  req.body.forEach(function (data) {
    console.log('received POST info');

    if (data.changed_aspect !== 'media') { 
      console.log('not an image');
      return;
    }

    request('https://api.instagram.com/v1/geographies/' + data.object_id + '/media/recent?client_id=' + clientID,
      function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) { 
          console.log('error');
          return;
        }

        console.log('request sent to Instagram');
        //Here we have one JSON object with all the info about the image
        var image = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(image.data[0]);

        //Save the new object to DB
        Stadium.findOneAndUpdate( {object_id: data.object_id}, { $push: {'photos':
          { img: image.data[0].images.standard_resolution.url,
            link: image.data[0].link,
            username: image.data[0].user.username,
            profile: image.data[0].user.profile_picture,
            text: image.data[0].caption ? image.data[0].caption.text : ''
          }}},
          { safe: true, upsert: false },
          function(err, model) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );

        //Send a socket to client with the new image
        newImage({
          img: image.data[0].images.standard_resolution.url,
          link: image.data[0].link,
          username: image.data[0].user.username,
          profile: image.data[0].user.profile_picture,
          text: image.data[0].caption ? image.data[0].caption.text : ''
        });
      }
    );
  });

  res.end();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
if (new Date('12-15-2014') <= Date.now() <= new Date('12-31-2014')) {
  // your code here. i.e handleEvent();
}
else {
  // nothing happens here
}
```

Just use the Date objects to set up your date range. As a note, I would also suggest moving the logic inside a containing method just to clean up the conditional a little.

Hope this helps!